# execute() gets no results

Tags: php, mysql

I have two queries here, $check_perms and $get_projects. The former seems to work, but not the latter. There's no error, just no results, yet I know there should be.

```
$sessionUser = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$check_perms = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = ?");
$check_perms->bind_param('i', $par);
    if ($result = $check_perms->execute())
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            if ($row['user'] != $sessionUser){
                echo "<container>Error. This is not your task.</container>";
                exit;
            }


$get_projects = Database::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE user = ? ORDER BY weight DESC");
$get_projects->bind_param('i', $sessionUser);
    if ($result = $get_projects->execute())
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            //stuff
```

Comment: i don't see any `echo` statement to display the result.

Comment: why are you reconnecting for the second query?

Comment: You are connecting to the db twice. Try doing first `$db = Database::connect();` And then replace the 2 occurances you have of `Database::connect()` with `$db`.

Comment: @nl-x Does that relate to the question? When I do this, `mysqli_fetch_assoc` fails.

Comment: I assume that you have cut out a load of code for brevity. If not, then the 2nd `if` statement eats your 2nd `prepare` statement, meaning the same query is run twice (once with `$par` and once with `$sessionUser`).

Comment: You're right, I'll update the OP so that's clear.

Comment: @user3733120 It's just a comment. Do with it what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `tasks.user` field is an integer? Try to change:

```
$check_perms->bind_param('i', $sessionUser);
```

to

```
$check_perms->bind_param('s', $sessionUser);
```

Comment: It's the second query that isn't working, he says. So your question back should be, `are you sure the parameter is an integer?` Try changing `'i'` with `'s'`. And I think you're on to something, as user is probably a string.

Comment: According to the OP, isn't the problem in `$get_projects` and not `check_perms`?

Comment: Ok, sorry, just edited for the opposite. The rush is never a good counselor

Comment: @kiks73 Tried it, but `$sessionID` and user are `ints`.

Comment: @user3733120 are you sure `user` is the correct column in your table? Shouldn't it be `user_id`? From convention I would expect `user` to be a username. And by the way, tasks.id is a string?